# Why I can't see ApiController's public methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an **ApiController** in my Asp.Net application and I want to use methods like **Ok(), NotFound(), BadRequest()** and so on instead of status codes. But for some reasons **these methods are not available in my ApiController** from System.Web.Http namespace. Please look at the following screenshot.

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Because it does not have them? Go to the definition of ApiController with F12 and you will see what it has to offer.

Comment: You can use Ok there, it's just that your return type is object. Change it to IHttpActionResult.

Comment: @StephenBrickner - any method declared to return `object` should be okay with returning absolutely anything at all - everything can be implicitly converted to `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of WebAPI are you using? You aren't using the right return type on the method declaration.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{ 
    var product = new Product();
    return Ok(product);
}
```

In newer version you can do the below, or something similar

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    return new OkResult(new HttpRequestMessage());
}
```

In addition you can use various others. I imagine you just got confused at how to access them:

```
new BadRequestResult(new HttpRequestMessage());
new NotFoundResult(new HttpRequestMessage());
```